Flexbox with flex-wrap leaves undesired empty horizontal space
in this example:
https://jsbin.com/sehuqowuca/edit?html,css,output
if I resized the view to be between 508px and 334px there is a horizontal space left and I can't fill it because of item2 height taking the whole row
How to get rid of this horizontal space and make item-3 fill that gap like this: https://imgur.com/a/x2EUmg3,
can I do such a thing with flex-box or I need to use a grid layout and if so how would I achieve it using grid ?


.flex-container{
  border:1px solid red;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:1rem;
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  gap:4rem;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.flex-item{
  border:1px solid lightblue;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius:5px
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item item-1">
    <h1>item1</h1>
    <h1>item1</h1>
 
  </div>
    <div class="flex-item item-2">
    <h1>item2</h1>
    <h1>item2</h1>
    <h1>item2</h1>
    <h1>item2</h1>
    <h1>item2</h1>
    <h1>item2</h1>
      
  </div>
    <div class="flex-item item-3">
    <h1>item3</h1>
    <h1>item3</h1>
    <h1>item3</h1>
    <h1>item3</h1>
    <h1>item3</h1>
    <h1>item3</h1>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>



